# low volume and poor sound quality on lenovo thinkpad 7th generation x1 carbon with dolby atmos speaker system and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, lenovo, thinkpad, speakers, 20.04

I have installed a Lenovo Thinkpad x1 Carbon (7th generation) with ubuntu 20.04. When I play music through the integrated Dolby Atmos speaker system, the sound quality is pretty poor and the volume is very low, even if I increase the volume to the maximum in the settings. I suspect that dolby atmos is not fully supported and that not all four speakers are activated.

Has someone encountered the same problem? And were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hello fellow Ubuntu user. This is a known bug with Ubuntu 20.04, you can follow the progress of the bug fix here : [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-ucm-conf/+bug/1872108](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-ucm-conf/+bug/1872108) Have a great day.

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue with my Dolby Atmos (Lenovo idea Pad). Very low volume and mediocre sound quality.