# Poor sound quality ThinkPad T490 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, thinkpad

Since install, I'm struggling with really bad audio quality on my ThinkPad. There's no deepness (no bass) sound is really quiet, even on 100% and really "poppy". For example, quiet slack notification sounds like speakers are dying.

I installed windows to check it and it was fine again, then re-install Ubuntu with all additional drivers and 3rd party software and nothing changed. Still poor...

Maybe someone may have any idea or solution for this issue.

Comment: Same on t495, on Windows sound is ok, on linux it;s crap. Looks like lenovo makes some drivers with presets for windows.

Comment: I have a ThinkPad T480, and I've given up trying to fix this issue; nothing I've tried works. It appears on Ubuntu, Fedora, and OpenSUSE Tumbleweed at least. However, you might be luckier than me, so here's some links containing suggestions.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108825/laptops-speakers-sound-bad-poor-sound-quality

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229979/low-volume-and-poor-sound-quality-on-lenovo-thinkpad-7th-generation-x1-carbon-wi